# Print multiple PDF pages on single paper

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe-reader

I have 4 separate pdf files. I need to print content in those files on a single paper like in below image.

[image: 4s]

Here is my current settings.

[image: adobe]

How can I select 4 page in my PC for printing?

Comment: You may need to merge the files into one PDF.  You can use PC-resident tools to do that, or do it with a web service like http://www.ilovepdf.com/merge_pdf.

Comment: I've heard of a program called PDFTools that may be able to do what you're after...

Answer (score 1):

Completed my task using [PDF Split and Merge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsam/) tool.